# Flexbox does not seem to be working as expected

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I know this will be a simple fix, and something I am probably blind to, but I am trying to create two columns using Flexbox. I want the page to look similar to this one: https://jadehomes.ca/floor-plans/, but rather than using `float`, I want to use Flexbox.

The page in question is: https://jadehomes.ca/360-tours/
The inspect tool should be enough to go off of.

```
<div class="row threesixty-tours-wrapper">
    <div class="threesixty-tours-container">
        <h3>Sapphire</h3>
        <a href="/contact" target="_blank" class=""><img src="uploads/image.jpg" alt="home plan image" class="threesixty-image"></a>
    </div>
</div>

.threesixty-tours-wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.threesixty-tours-container {
    flex: 50%;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Kyle, please include a [mcve] of your code here in the question. Otherwise it is likely to be closed.

Comment: Extract unnecessary code and only include what's important please. For example you have some php that does something unknown.

Comment: I have simplified the code.

Comment: `.threesixty-tours-wrapper` specified display flex, but you've only got one element in it, `threesixty-tours-container`. An appraoach to creating a 2 column layout would be by setting `grid-template-columns` to `repeat(2, 1fr)`.